# How to make MySQL 8 compatible with MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have MySQL 8.x running on my local dev enviroment while tansitioning my infrastructure to it. There are serves on prod running 5.7 and at this stage I am trying to import a dump from the 8.x server to the 5.7 server.

As far as I can see all character set are to utf8_unicode_ci. However I can not import the dump as it somehow contains lines like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE `dbname` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
```

I already added this config to my.cnf and restarted the dev server:

```
collation_server        = utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server    = utf8

show variables like "character_set_database"
variable_name    Value
character_set_database    utf8
```

Also changed the db:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 3719 | 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous. |
| Warning | 3778 | 'utf8_unicode_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.                              |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cant't find anywhere in the db the _900_ai CHAR SET, however it is somehow in the dump of the db.

```
ALTER DATABASE `dbname` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
ALTER DATABASE `dbname` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
```

How can I change the character set for the entire DBMS to utf8_unicode_ci so I can export/import between MySQL5.7 and 8.x?

Comment: Alter database properties on dev server and set its character set and collation to compatible values.

Comment: I did change it  (updated questions with details), but somehow the new export still contains the alter db command.

Comment: You change server charset/collation, not database ones. Use ALTER DATABASE statement (beware - this may affect on many other things, maybe make DB backup on dev, restore on dev to temporary DB, alter tempDB charset/collation, backup tempDB, then restore on prod). `character_set_database` affects on newly created DB only.

Comment: I just did 'ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;' but the dump still contains the mentioned char set.